# STM32L053 + SPI only works at the first cycle

Tags: stm32, spi, hal

Actually i am testing with the microcontroller STM32L053 and i am using stm32cubeide with hal.

This are my first steps with this microcontroller and ide. I am using an e-paper that i have connected using SPI and e-paper stm32 library (https://github.com/soonuse/epd-library-stm32/tree/master/1.54inch_e-paper/stm32)

In my first cycle the e-paper works well and i can display some figurs and text but when the while start again the e-paper not show nothing. It is the similar case if i use the stop mode. If i use standby mode the e-paper works well because in this mode the microcontroller is reset and the program starts.

I think that i am doind something wrong with the SPI interface.

This is my SPI inicialization code:

```
/**

* @brief SPI1 Initialization Function

* @param None

* @retval None

*/

static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)

{ 
/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

/* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

/* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */

/* SPI1 parameter configuration*/

hspi1.Instance = SPI1;

hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;

hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE;

hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;

hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;

hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;

hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;

hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;

hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;

hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;

hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;

hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;

if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK) 
{ 
Error_Handler(); 
} 
/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

/* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */ 
}
```

This is the code to entry in stop mode and the next code lines that they are executed:

```
/* Enter Stop Mode */

__HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);

HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1, (uint8_t*)”Sleep mode activated...\r\n”, sizeof(“Sleep mode activated...\r\n”), 20);

HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);


/* Configures system clock after wake-up from STOP: enable HSE, PLL and select

PLL as system clock source (HSE and PLL are disabled in STOP mode) */

//HAL_Init();

SystemClock_Config();

MX_GPIO_Init();

MX_ADC_Init();

MX_LPUART1_UART_Init();

MX_USART2_UART_Init();

MX_RTC_Init();

MX_SPI1_Init();

MX_TIM2_Init();

HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1, (uint8_t*)”Wake-Up...\r\n”, sizeof(“Wake-Up...\r\n”), 20);
```